# Generate random numbers and characters - MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How to create a table that generates numbers and characters randomly to use as a passing code for users?

here's my code:

```
create table reservation(rID int auto_increment, rCode varchar(255) magic_number, user varchar(255), address varchar(255), room_type varchar(255), primary key(rID));
```

When user completely signed all fields required, informations will be transferred to database, and automatically the column `rCode` will generate a random code, maybe a combination of integers and/or characters(a-z only).

Response is will help me finished this project. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the intended use of the random code?

Comment: It will submit to the users email address(I never include the email address to my example above).

Comment: I pressume the code will need to be unique per user? *Side Note:* I love how similar the 2 answers are haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a PHP function that generates a random string

```
function rand_string( $length )
{
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    $size = strlen( $chars );
    $str = "";
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just need a simple random hash, you could use all the crypto-possibilities of mysql. Here is an example fpr your situation:

```
INSERT INTO reservation (
    rCode, user, address, room_type
) VALUES (
    SHA1(NOW()), 'the name', 'the address', 'the room'
);
```

If you need a certain length (lets say 8) just use substring:

```
SUBSTRING(SHA1(NOW()), 0, 8)
```

Or even better:

```
SUBSTRING(SHA1(NOW()), ROUND(RAND() * 100) % 32, 8)
```

The last one generates a random starting point from 0 to 32 and uses the following 8 digits as your code (a sha1 is always 40 chars long...therefore the 32). if you need for example 10 chars for your code, just replace the 8 with 10 and the 32 with 30.

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function for generating random code.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

You can generate a random alphanumeric code by calling thi function with the length of the code passing as argument.

Ex: `$code = generateRandomString(5);`

This will return a 5 character long code and will be stored in `$code`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //update code_bazaryab fake not have code
         $model = new \Modules\Membership\Models\user();

        $rows = $model->get_all_null_code_bazaryabi();
        foreach($rows as $row){

            $chars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

            $size = strlen( $chars );
            $str = "";
            for( $i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i++ ) {
                $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
            }

            $model->update_user(['code_bazaryab'=>$str],['userid'=>$row->userid]);

        }
```